# Differences in C++ fomatting using Indigo and Kepler/Luna

Tags: c++, eclipse, formatter

we have created a C++ code style template that does the following formatting:

```
if (true)
    return;
```

In the Indigo release of Eclipse this is working fine.
But in Kepler and I also just tried the new Luna release it looks like this:

```
if (true)
return;
```

The same behaviour is shown using the K&R [build-in] formatter.

The following is working in all Eclipse releases:

```
if (true)
{
     return;
}
```

Any idea how I can reach the correct formatting (with white spaces) in the Kepler release?
Thanks a lot,
Andrea

Answer (score 0):

Right-click on the code window and select Preferences.
C/C++->Code style->Formatter
Here you can select the format you wish,import and edit.

I am using Luna myself and found this to be the easiest way to reach this menu.